# Require a file within itself in node.js

Tags: node.js, require

How do you require a file within itself in node.js? E.g. api.js:

```
var api = require(./api.js);
```

What is the best practice for doing this?

Comment: The best practice is to not do this.

Comment: Please elaborate . . .

Comment: Obviously you can just define functions but is that the only reason this is ill-advised?

Comment: What problem is this supposed to solve?

Comment: The point of `require()` is to load a module.  But, if you're already in the module, it is already loaded, so there really is no point to try to load it again from within itself.  Likely all you need to do is to call a function within your module, but since you haven't explained what problem you're really trying to solve, we can't provide more specific help.

Comment: Please explain why you need to do this. I can't think up a case where it would be important to do this, and it would just cause a dependency loop (api.js requires api.js which require api.js, etc, in a circle). And you'll still have to define all the functions in the file somewhere

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can totally do it. Try this, for instance (in a file named `a.js`):

```
exports.foo = 'foo';

var a = require('./a');

console.log(a);

exports.bar = 'bar';

console.log(a);
```

At the point where `require` executes, it will return the module `a` as it exists at the point where `require` runs so the field `foo` will be defined but not `bar`.

There's no point to doing this though. You use `require` to bring into your current scope an object which would otherwise not be available (namely, a module). **But you don't need to do this to access the module you are currently in: it is already fully available.**

The code above works because Node has rules to handle [cyclic dependencies](http://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_cycles). And here you have a module which is cyclicly dependent on itself. Rather than go into an infinite loop of requires, Node has `require` return the module as built up to that point: a partial module. And the modules in a cyclic dependency have to be designed to handle the fact that they may get partial modules.

**Cyclic dependencies are to be avoided as much as possible.** Most of the time this means refactoring the modules to avoid the mutual dependency by moving functionality into one or more new modules.

**So, again, the best practice is to not do this in the first place.**

Comment: yeah I am writing a program that could potential be given an argument from the command line that represents the same file that is about to run, and so the file could potential require itself, and it happened, but it didn't re-require itself as you say

Comment: in other words: node index.js --files index.js